# Android:picture from Camera and gallery runtime exception

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery

Following is the log cat of my error:

```
 03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to    resume activity {com.example.camtest1/com.example.camtest1.MainActivity}: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at  android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2639)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1279)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4935)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486): Caused by: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.throwIfCursorIsClosed(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:64)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.requery(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:133)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at android.database.CursorWrapper.requery(CursorWrapper.java:186)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:5246)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5272)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2629)
  03-08 13:20:36.193: E/AndroidRuntime(9486):   ... 10 more
```

I am unable to accertain where my code is going wrong. Following is the code with which I try to capture or select a picture from Gallery with Samsung handling done:

```
   import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.content.DialogInterface;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.graphics.Bitmap;
   import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.provider.MediaStore;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


String picturePath;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;
int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337; 
Bitmap thumbnail = null; 
private static final int OG=4; 

private static final int CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 0;
Uri u;
ImageView imgview;
//int z=0;
String z=null;
byte b[];
String largeImagePath = "";
Uri uriLargeImage;
Uri uriThumbnailImage;
Cursor myCursor;





 public void imageCam(Bitmap thumbnail){
        Bitmap photo = thumbnail; 
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bos);
        b = bos.toByteArray();
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    //  Bitmap bt=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, 200, 400, false);  
        imageview.setImageBitmap(photo);

    }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt.setOnClickListener(onBTN);
    if( savedInstanceState != null ) {
        //if()
        Bitmap Zatang; 
        String B1 = savedInstanceState .getString("message");
        Toast.makeText(this, "SavedYeah"+B1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inSampleSize = OG;
        // thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        Zatang = BitmapFactory.decodeFile((B1), opts);
        System.gc();
        if(Zatang != null){
             Toast.makeText(this, "Success Zatang"+B1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             imageCam(Zatang);

         }
        String B12 = savedInstanceState .getString("Gallerymessage"); 
        if(B12 != null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Recreated on Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            BitmapFactory.Options opts1 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opts.inSampleSize = OG;
           // thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile((B12), opts1);
            System.gc();
            imageCam(thumbnail);

        }

}

}


private View.OnClickListener onBTN = new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        openNewGameDialog();
    }
};
String []B = {"Camera", "Gallery"};


private void openNewGameDialog(){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setItems(B,new       DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface,int i){
                if(i==0){
                    String BX1 =  android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;

                    if(BX1.equalsIgnoreCase("samsung")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device man"+BX1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    }
                    else {
                         Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                         startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST); 
                    }
                }

                else if (i==1){
                     // Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                     // startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);


                      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                      intent.setType("image/*");
                      startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                }




           }
           })
           .show();
   }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if(requestCode==CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){

        // Describe the columns you'd like to have returned. Selecting from the Thumbnails location gives you both the Thumbnail Image ID, as well as the original image ID
         String[] projection = {
         MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,  // The columns we want
         MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,
         MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND,
         MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA};
         String selection = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND + "="  + // Select only mini's
         MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND;

         String sort = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID + " DESC";

        //At the moment, this is a bit of a hack, as I'm returning ALL images, and just taking the latest one. There is a better way to narrow this down I think with a WHERE clause which is currently the selection variable
        myCursor = this.managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, sort);

        long imageId = 0l;
        long thumbnailImageId = 0l;
        String thumbnailPath = "";

        try{

            myCursor.moveToFirst();
            imageId = myCursor.getLong(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID));
            thumbnailImageId = myCursor.getLong(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID));
            thumbnailPath = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
            }
        finally{
            myCursor.close();
            }

            //Create new Cursor to obtain the file Path for the large image

                String[] largeFileProjection = {
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA
                };

                String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID + " DESC";
                myCursor = this.managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);
                largeImagePath = "";

                try{
                    myCursor.moveToFirst();

                    //This will actually give yo uthe file path location of the image.
                    largeImagePath = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
                }
                finally{myCursor.close();}
                // These are the two URI's you'll be interested in. They give you a handle to the actual images
                uriLargeImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(imageId));
                uriThumbnailImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(thumbnailImageId));

                // I've left out the remaining code, as all I do is assign the URI's to my own objects anyways...
                // Toast.makeText(this, ""+largeImagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Toast.makeText(this, ""+uriLargeImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Toast.makeText(this, ""+uriThumbnailImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                if(largeImagePath != null ){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "LARGE YES"+largeImagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                     BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                     opts.inSampleSize = OG;
                     // thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                     thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile((largeImagePath), opts);
                     System.gc();
                     if(thumbnail != null){
                         Toast.makeText(this, "Try Without Saved Instance", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         imageCam(thumbnail);
                     }




                }if(uriLargeImage != null){


                    Toast.makeText(this, ""+uriLargeImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();





                }if(uriThumbnailImage != null){


                    Toast.makeText(this, ""+uriThumbnailImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                }



         }
         if( requestCode == 1337 && resultCode== RESULT_OK){
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                //  if (extras!=null){  
                if (extras.keySet().contains("data") ){

                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        // options.inSampleSize = 1;
                        // options.inPurgeable = true;
                        // options.inInputShareable = true;
                        thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                        //  image(thumbnail);
                        if (thumbnail != null){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "YES Thumbnail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            // options.inSampleSize = 1;
                            // options.inPurgeable = true;
                            // options.inInputShareable = true;
                            thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                            imageCam(thumbnail);
                        }

                    }else{

                    Uri imageURI = getIntent().getData();
                    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    imageview.setImageURI(imageURI);

                    if(imageURI != null){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "YES Image Uri", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }





                       // Toast.makeText(CreateProfile.this, "Picture NOt taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
         }
         if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    opts.inSampleSize = OG;
                   // thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                    thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile((picturePath), opts);
                    System.gc();
                    imageCam(thumbnail);

             }

                 else
                 {
                    // imgview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bbtb);
                 }

         }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
       super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
       outState.putString("message",largeImagePath );
       outState.putString("Gallerymessage",picturePath );


    }
```

}

Comment: I am having the same problem...Did u got the solution for this???

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it transpired that on some devices / API levels when the camera intent is used, onDestroy() was being called. In my onDestroy I was closing the cursors and database as you would normally do.

You can fix this by checking if database is .open and cursor==null in either:
onActivityResult or onResume then reopening and updating the cursor if required.

```
if (!database.isOpen() || database==null) {
    patternsdb helper = new patternsdb(main.this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```